# WebP support in WKWebView from iOS 14

Tags: ios, webkit, wkwebview, webp

Does WKWebView support WebP images? If so, how can I enable this? I have only found old questions that stated that it is not possible, however [since iOS 14 Safari should have support for WebP](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/safari-release-notes/safari-14-release-notes).

My use case is that I have local css, js and html files and would like to present all of it in WKWebView. Some elements that use jpg/png images show up correctly but not those that use WebP images.

Is there some update or it is still not possible?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that Xcode cached my initial setup where my resources resided in Group instead of a Folder so the page was displayed incorrectly.

WKWebView is now working and displaying WebP - therefore I think we can conclude that WKWebView now supports WebP